# error while trying to define a vector in julia, parsing

Tags: julia

Perhaps is in older versions of julia, mine is  `Version 0.5.0-dev+2007 2016-01-05 18:26 UTC)`, but if you define:

```
julia> [1 +2,1]
ERROR: syntax: unexpected comma in matrix expression
in eval at ./boot.jl:265
```

Yo have to either define `[1+2,1]` or `[1 + 2, 1]`. Is this on purpose?

Answer (score 4):

This is because Julia is parsing the `+2` as the number "positive 2" and not treating the `+` as the addition operator. Since vectors of the form `[a b,c]` are invalid, you get the error.